# Laravel: Ajax update to database

Tags: ajax, laravel

i just want to update my data via ajax i am getting error.
**Error Console:**

> POST http://abc.local/teachers/users/1 404 (Not Found)

here is my controller:

```
public function policyupdate(Request $request, $id)
              {

         $user = DB::table('users')->find($id);
        $user->update($request->all());
          return response()->json([
            'status' => 'success',
            'msg' => 'has been updated'
        ]);
         }
```

**web.php:**

```
Route::post('users/{user}','TeachersController@policyupdate') ;
```

**js:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(e)  {
  alert(1);
$('#update-policy').on('click', function(e) {
console.log('Update policy clicked!')
    e.preventDefault(e);

        $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
            url: "users/" + $('#update-policy').attr("value"),
        data:  $(this).serialize(),
        headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      },

            success: function (data) {
          alert(updated);
              },

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: add a slash on the begening of the url `url: "/users/" + $('#update-policy').attr("value"),`

Comment: got error: POST http://abc.local/users/15 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Comment: Do you have any other route with the same uri? maybe a resource route with the uri `users` or something like`Route::put('users/{user}', 'UsersController@update');` or `Route::get('users/{user}','UsersController@show');`

Comment: i opened route:list and there is nothing like that, maybe something is wrong here?<form  id="policy-form" method="put"  enctype="multipart/form-data" >
              <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put" />

Comment: Ohh, you are sending an input with _method put, so your route should be    `Route::put('users/{user}','TeachersController@policyupdate') ;`

Comment: now: Call to undefined method stdClass::update() in controller.

Comment: please add answer so i can mark as complete. $user = DB::table('users')->where('id', '=' , $id);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only notice a couple of issues.

```
url: "users/" + $('#update-policy').attr("value"),
```

In the url of the ajax call you don't have a slash at the beginning, so the url will be relative to the url of the page where the function is located, instead of the base url. to solve it just add that slash at the beginning

```
url: "/users/" + $('#update-policy').attr("value"),
```

The other one is that you have an input with the put method,

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put" />
```

so the Laravel route should be put (it makes sense if it takes into account that it is a route to update)

```
Route::put('users/{user}','TeachersController@policyupdate') ;
```

Well, and as you yourself discovered, with query builder, the `update()` method works if you query with `where()` instead of `find()`

```
$user = DB::table('users')->where('id', $id)->update( $request->all() );
```